# Encrypting files on SD card and sharing it with other apps

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I would like to store a file on SD card, lets say an mp3 file and encrypt it.

And would like other apps to be able to play them but BB automatically decrypt them?(Does DRMManager do this?)

Basically, I would like to keep the mp3 files locked to the BB device. If they tried to open the mp3 on say a desktop or another BB, they won't be able to open them.

As long as the mp3s are accessed from the same BB they should open fine, using any mp3 player app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is exactly what the enableDRMForwardLock() method in [ExtendedFileConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/device/api/io/file/ExtendedFileConnection.html) is for.